# What are the “Dynamic Manoeuvres” in Dark Souls?

Tags: actions, dark-souls-rpg

In the Dark Souls tabletop RPG, one of the uses for spending Position is (p.103):

> Perform one Dynamic Manoeuvre. These are special actions, enabling you to do extraordinary things, pushing yourself beyond normal limits and embrace[sic] the power of the unkindled. The details of dynamic manoeuvres and their costs are shown in more detail below.

I could find no other mention of Dynamic Manoeuvres anywhere in the rules. Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not in the USA: https://eu.steamforged.com/products/dark-souls-roleplaying-game

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135294/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-marq).

Answer (score 7):

It looks as though this is an error that will be corrected and the books reissued, there appear to have been a number of errors, poor editing (As you noted in your chat).

As reported on the [gaming website IGN](https://sea.ign.com/dark-souls/184424/news/dark-souls-ttrpg-rulebook-riddled-with-errors-dev-apologizes-and-promises-reissue) (Note-The players name from the quoted section on the site links to the reddit discussion):

> Reddit user arh231201 highlighted that players are told they can make "dynamic manoeuvres", but the book doesn't explain at any point what these are.

> Some items also don't appear to make sense, as the Firelink Sword lets you spend two position points to gain one back, while the Soul of Cinder lets you cast spells when certain requirements are met, but it doesn't come equipped with any.